# Добавление элементов в select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь сделать чтобы при изменении выбора в одном `select` в другой `select` добавлялся элемент:

```js
$("#slct").change(function() {
  var id_prod = $("#slct").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/admin-panel/specz.php',
    data: {
      prod: id_prod
    }
  }).then(function(response) {
    $('#spp').prepend('<option value="1">55555</option>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker show-tick" data-style="btn-white" name="prod" id="slct" required>
  <option value="1">Не менять</option>
  <option value="2">Еще один</option>
</select>

<select class="selectpicker show-tick" data-style="btn-white" name="prod" id="spp" required>
  <option value="1">Второе</option>
</select>
```

Но элемент не добавляет.

А если код `$('#spp').prepend('<option value="1">55555</option>');` вынести отдельно за всю конструкцию - то сразу при загрузки страницы элемент добавляет.

Хотя *POST* идет на файл нормально, даже ответ получаю.

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Покажите ваш HTML код

Comment: @Arsen добавил в вопрос

Comment: А ты пробовал не через `then` добавлять, а через  `success`?

Comment: @Yuri просто заменить `then` на `success` ? только что попробовал - все равно не добавляет

Comment: @Денис, `success` добавляется туда же где и `data`. `success` представляет собой функцию. (Пример: `$.ajax({data: {...}, success: function(data) {...}})`). Эта функция вызовится, когда придёт успешный ответ

Comment: А вы раскрываете список, смотрите, что элемент не появился, или думаете, что он выбранным сам встанет по умолчанию?

Comment: @Crantisz раскрываю конечно

Comment: Голосую за закрытие вопроса, т.к. проблема не воспроизводится или вызвана опечаткой.

Answer (score 0):

Все работает. Ошибки нет:

```js
$("#slct").change(function() {
  var id_prod = $("#slct").val();
  console.log('Нажата кнопка')
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://httpbin.org/get',
    data: {
      prod: id_prod
    }
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log('Запрос отправлен')
    $('#spp').prepend('<option value="1">55555</option>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker show-tick" data-style="btn-white" name="prod" id="slct" required>
  <option value="1">Поменяйте здесь</option>
  <option value="2">Поменял</option>
</select>

<select class="selectpicker show-tick" data-style="btn-white" name="prod" id="spp" required>
  <option value="1">Смотрите потом тут</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Сейчас оно не должно, по-моему, добавлять. Так как запрос не отправляется..

Comment: @Yuri, так я не дурак, `url` поменял, чтобы работало

Comment: Хех.. этого я не увидел :) Скорее всего у автора какая-то дичь там. И проверил и свой вариант - всё работает хорошо

Comment: что-то не работает. странно. может быть из-за того что подключены различные js файлы у меня?

Comment: @Денис вообщем, вы поняли, косяк у вас не в этом месте. Может URL не верен, может еще что-то. Смотрите ошибки в консоли

Comment: @Crantisz я с вашим запросом пробую - то же самое

Comment: @Денис, а вы вообще с сервера запрос делаете, или просто с компьютера запустили html и отправляете?

Comment: @Yuri у меня Open Server стоит

Comment: @Yuri оказывается в обычный select добавляет, а в это мешает class

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавлять через функцию [`success`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```js
$("#slct").change(function() {
  var id_prod = $("#slct").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/admin-panel/specz.php',
    data: {
      prod: id_prod
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#spp').prepend('<option value="1">55555</option>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker show-tick" data-style="btn-white" name="prod" id="slct" required>
  <option value="1">Не менять</option>
  <option value="2">Еще один</option>
</select>

<select class="selectpicker show-tick" data-style="btn-white" name="prod" id="spp" required>
  <option value="1">Второе</option>
</select>
```

Comment: не помогает это

Comment: @Денис, вы вообще проверяли запрос? Мне кажется, у вас там ошибка.